# How can I store request-local information in Yesod middleware and retrieve it from a Handler?

Tags: yesod, middleware

Before any handler code is executed, I need to load some information about the user, which is determined by the request cookies, and then access that in all of my handler code.

I've looked at the [yesod-core](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod) codebase and found that I could override the `yesodMiddleware` function and provide a custom middleware which would load the data before the handler is executed.

The problem is that I don't know where to store this data, so that I can later retrieve it from the `Handler`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cached and cachedBy](http://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-1.8/yesod-core-1.4.8/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:cached) for per-request caching.